# Как перебрать ipset и добавить новые из файла?

Tags: linux, bash, iptables, ipset

Как перебрать ipset badips и добавить туда новый ip a.b.c.d, если его нет в этом списке? Что-то типа,но не знаю как правильно:

```
sudo cat iplist.txt | while read line
do
 if($(ipset test badips $line)=='$line is NOT in set bots') sudo ipset -A badips $line
done
```

Comment: [предыдущая версия](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1007209/178576)

Comment: интересно посмотреть как выглядит `ipset list` вывод, если я правильно помню то командой что-то вроде этого можно проверить какие ip есть в файле, но нет в ipset: `cat iplist.txt | grep -v "$(ipset list | grep -Po '^[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}')"`, далее их можно будет обработать по циклу с добавлением.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу смысла в скрипте если ipset сам проверяет присутствие ip

```
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ sudo ipset create example hash:ip 
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ sudo ipset add example 127.0.0.1
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ sudo ipset add example 127.0.2.1
[eri@eri-macro ~]$ sudo ipset add example 127.0.2.1
ipset v7.2: Element cannot be added to the set: it's already added
```